# Applying rollify to calculate percentrank

Tags: r, rank

I have the table Wide_DF similar to the below structure( more rows than below)

| DATE | TICKER | Total_Put |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-03 | A | 23.4 |
| 2021-01-03 | B | 13.1 |
| 2021-01-03 | C | 34.6 |

The colum TICKER has 3 values A,B,C, i.e the data for each ticker for all dates, and dates in descending order

My goal is to have a 4th column explaining the percentile of Total_Put with the last 60 values

This is my approach

```
rankCalc <- tibbletime::rollify( ~percent_rank(.x), window = 60)



Wide_DF = Wide_DF %>%
          dplyr::group_by(TICKER) %>%
          dplyr::mutate(ROW_VALUE = rankCalc(Total_Put )) %>%
          dplyr::ungroup()
```

But I get the following error

> Error in `dplyr::mutate()`:
> ℹ In argument: `ROW_VALUE=rankCalc(Total_Put )`.
> ℹ In group 1: `TICKER = "A"`.
> Caused by error:
> ! `ROW_VALUE` must be size 1060 or 1, not 60119.

It looks like an error due to the window size, but I verified the window size is appropriate by replacing rank with mean and the code works. Even my Wide_DF has 3000 rows

What looks like the possible error ?

Comment: use `reframe` instead of `mutate`